# How can I group RadioButtons without a GroupBox in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to group RadioButtons, but I don't want to use the visible control GroupBox. Is there something like the [Java ButtonGroup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) in VB.NET?

Comment: How do you want to group them? What do you mean by group? That they are mutually exclusive? If so, use RadioButtonList.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net?

Comment: I'm using VB.NET, so WinForms

Comment: VB.Net can also use WPF, Silverlight, and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Panel` control.

Comment: +1 The `Panel` control is the best way to 'borderlessly' group radio/option boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist_members.aspx)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id=RadioButtonList1 runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you could alter an asp:RadioButtonList [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: He's almost definitely using WinForms.